# How to vertically center text adjacent to image in grid alignment?

Tags: html, css

Trying to vertically center align text next to an image in a three across grid alignment. Have tried many things but either one of two things happens:
- text vertically center aligns for one row of text, but wraps under the image if there is more than one row of text
- text wraps properly for multiple rows of text, but won't vertically center align, as shown in the provided code

Any suggestions?

```css
.tile-third {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.tile-image {
  vertical-align:middle;
  float:left;
  margin-right: 1%;
  background-color:#000;
}

.tile-text {
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-third">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="tile-image" src="http://acmebeachandbike.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/icon-outside.png"/>
        <div class="tile-text">Department Description One (DD1)</div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="tile-third">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="tile-image" src="http://acmebeachandbike.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/icon-lowimpact.png"/>
        <span class="tile-text">Department Description Two</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="tile-third">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="tile-image" src="http://acmebeachandbike.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/icon-fun.png"/>
        <span class="tile-text">Department Description Three (DD3)</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: two answers are essentially the same solution. but  @saurabh was quicker by 10 minutes and is slightly simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for??

```css
.tile-third {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 30%;
}

.tile-third > a {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.tile-image {
  background-color:#000;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.tile-text {
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-third">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="tile-image" src="http://acmebeachandbike.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/icon-outside.png"/>
        <div class="tile-text">Department Description One (DD1)</div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="tile-third">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="tile-image" src="http://acmebeachandbike.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/icon-lowimpact.png"/>
        <span class="tile-text">Department Description Two</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="tile-third">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="tile-image" src="http://acmebeachandbike.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/icon-fun.png"/>
        <span class="tile-text">Department Description Three (DD3)</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I set the `display` value for the `<a>` tag under the `<div class="tile-third">` to `flex` which is an easy way to get things to properly align.

This allows the `<img>` and `<div>` inside the `<a>` to properly align.

Comment: thanks for correcting this - didn't realize until shortly after posting but you corrected it quickly, and didn't need to fix it myself. thank you!

Comment: even though the images are the same size, in my implementation, Firefox scales the images, causing the bottom of the tiles to be different heights, while Chrome preserves image size and maintains consistent tile height (and alignment). Any suggestions how to address this Firefox-specific challenge?

Comment: can you provide links to the actual images so I can test on Firefox?

Comment: prefer not to hard code image height and width properties, allowing the browser to scale images as necessary, but was forced to in this case. apparently there are plenty of cross-browser flexbox inconsistencies (nicely summarized by the same author):
https://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/
https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Answer (score 1):

the image and the text is inside in an anchor tag,
change the style of the anchor tag to achieve the required.

example,

```
.tile-third a {
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Creating a CSS selector as simple as `a` is a recipe for disaster since this will affect *every* `<a>` tag on the page. Yes this solution will work, but it is much better to not use just an element selector.